# The meaning of the attenuation coefficient (Computer Tomography)

Tags: radiation, x-rays

I've been sorting out the process of detecting the signal in Computer Tomography and met a problem with undestanding of the meaning of the attenuation coefficient. Here's the pic that made me feel confused.

[image]

As far as you can see, there's a constant value of $f(\frac {1}{2},x_1) = 1 $ for some values of $x_1$ right at the position of entering the object.

According to the attenuation coefficient definition I have

$$ f(\frac{1}{2}, x_1) = \frac{-\frac{dI}{I(x_1)}}{dx_1} $$

So since the intensity at the position of entering the object is equal to the initial intensity and $f = 1$ in the interval $[x_1, x_1+dx_1]$, I'll have all the intensity absorbed in this layer, hence I won't have anything in the output. But how does it work then?..

The image was taken from the book named Linear and nonlinear inverse problems with practical applications-Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics by Jennifer L. Müller and Samuli Siltanen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the expression for the attenuation coefficient as

$$\frac{dI(x_1)}{dx_1}=-f(\frac{1}{2},x_1)\cdot I(x_1)$$

This shows that the rate at which the intensity is reduced is proportional to the local intensity with as proportionality constant the attenuation coefficient.

If $f(\frac{1}{2},x_1)$ is a constant,i.e.$f=f(\frac{1}{2})$, this will lead to an intensity profile:

$$I(x_1)=I(0) e^{-f(\frac{1}{2})\cdot x_1}.$$

You can check that this intensity profile satisfies the equality above. The intensity thus decays exponentially over the distance. After each distance $\Delta x=\frac{1}{f(\frac{1}{2})}$ the intensity has been reduced by a factor $e$.

In your case the attenuation coefficient is not constant, so you will get various exponential decays after each other. Each with a different decay rate.